# SQL GROUP BY COUNT and Include 0 Values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the below simple table where I am using group by to get a count of fruit type by country.  However, I would like to include 0 values where the country did not have any quantity of the fruit type. The current query I have excludes the 0 values where country does not have that fruit type. How include it so that the country that does not have that fruit type is displayed with a 0 value as show in my desired output?

Including Sample Table SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE1` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `COUNTRY` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `FRUIT` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));
INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (`ID`, `COUNTRY`, `FRUIT`) VALUES ('1', 'Mexico', 'Mango');
INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (`ID`, `COUNTRY`, `FRUIT`) VALUES ('2', 'Brazil', 'Mango');
INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (`ID`, `COUNTRY`, `FRUIT`) VALUES ('3', 'Brazil', 'Orange');
INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (`ID`, `COUNTRY`, `FRUIT`) VALUES ('4', 'Brazil', 'Orange');
INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (`ID`, `COUNTRY`, `FRUIT`) VALUES ('5', 'Mexico', 'Apple');
INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (`ID`, `COUNTRY`, `FRUIT`) VALUES ('6', 'Brazil', 'Grape');
INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (`ID`, `COUNTRY`, `FRUIT`) VALUES ('7', 'Brazil', 'Pear');
```

**Sample Table:**

```
Id  Country  Fruit
------------------
1   Mexico   Mango
2   Brazil   Mango
3   Brazil   Orange
4   Brazil   Orange
5   Mexico   Apple
6   Brazil   Grape
7   Brazil   Pear
```

**Group By:**

```
SELECT COUNTRY, FRUIT, COUNT(COUNTRY) as NUM FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY FRUIT, COUNTRY
ORDER BY COUNTRY
```

**Current Output:**

```
    Country Fruit   Count    
    Brazil  Mango   1
    Brazil  Grape   1
    Brazil  Orange  2
    Brazil  Pear    1
    Mexico  Mango   1
    Mexico  Apple   1
```

**Desired Output:**

```
    Country Fruit   Count  
    Brazil  Mango   1
    Brazil  Mango   0
    Brazil  Grape   1
    Mexico  Grape   0
    Brazil  Orange  2
    Mexico  Orange  0
    Brazil  Pear    1
    Mexico  Pear    0
    Mexico  Mango   1
    Brazil  Mango   0
    Mexico  Apple   1
    Brazil  Apple   0
```

Comment: See JOIN. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find all the distinct values of `Country` and `Fruit` and CROSS JOIN them; this can then be `LEFT JOIN`ed to your table to get the counts for each `Country/Fruit` combination:

```
SELECT c.Country,
       f.Fruit,
       COUNT(t.Fruit) AS Count
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM table1
) c
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT Fruit FROM table1
) f
LEFT JOIN table1 t ON t.Country = c.Country and t.Fruit = f.Fruit
GROUP BY c.Country, f.Fruit
```

Output:

```
Country     Fruit   Count
Brazil      Apple   0
Brazil      Grape   1
Brazil      Mango   1
Brazil      Orange  2
Brazil      Pear    1
Mexico      Apple   1
Mexico      Grape   0
Mexico      Mango   1
Mexico      Orange  0
Mexico      Pear    0
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tfVatQgDSqWgZLSiBZ4PAq/0)

Comment: Thank you. Was not aware of the cross join. Exactly what I was lookin for. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't really need (quite so many) subqueries here

Comment: @Strawberry how do you figure that? You need to get a cartesian product of the `Country` and `Fruit` values before you can join to the original table?

Comment: Sure, but you can do the distinct bit on both.

Comment: @Strawberry you mean `SELECT DISTINCT Country, Fruit FROM table1`? that won't get all combinations. I'm not following you, could you perhaps edit my demo to show me what you mean?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f6secwoV6B4HSQderW68Es/0

Comment: @Strawberry gotcha - I was trying to figure out how to do it without the second `JOIN`. No wonder I was confused :-P

Comment: @Strawberry the execution plans are similar, but I suspect mine is more efficient as it only has to do `DISTINCT` over 14 rows (2x7) instead of 49...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this.

Cartesian product the fruits with the countries. This will get you all country-fruit combinations.
Once you get this perform a left join with your table and perform the group by.

```
with all_fruits
  as (select distinct fruit
        from table1
     )    
    ,all_countries  
  as(select distinct country
        from table1
     )
    ,fruit_country
   as(select country,fruit
        from all_fruits
        join all_countries
     )
    select a.country
          ,a.fruit
          ,count(b.fruit) as count
     from fruit_country a
left join table1 b
       on a.country=b.country
      and a.fruit=b.fruit 
 group by a.country
         ,a.fruit
```